# Is there a theorem based on substitution to convert a congruency to an equality?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am working on my own version of a proof of RSA and have come do a conclusion based on these simplified statements.
Given: N = pq
X ≡ 1 (mod p)
X ≡ 1 (mod q)
X ≡ 1 (mod N) by chinese remainder theorem

I have the original expression:
MX ≡ M' (mod N)

When substituting X ≡ 1 (mod N) into this equation, is it correct to say that
M = M' (removing the modulus) or must I say M ≡ M' (mod N)?

Comment: Have you created a few examples and test cases to see?

Comment: i guess that would be a good thing to start with

Comment: hm. it seems like my train of thought here is totally inaccurate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT** $\ $ No,$\ $ e.g.$\ $ let $\rm\ M'\: =\: M + N\:.\ $  But the inference that $\rm\ M'\equiv M\ (mod\ N)\ $ is correct since it's a special case of the [congruence product rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/very-simple-question-but-what-is-the-proof-that-x-y-mod-m-x-mod-m-y-mod-m/5376#5376) viz. $\rm\ X\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ M\:X \equiv M\cdot 1 \equiv M\:,\:$ i.e. $\rm\ M'\equiv M\:$.

Comment: but I could say that M ≡ M' (mod N)?

Comment: Yes, see my link to the congruence product rule.