# Basic question about mod

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm having a tough time understanding why $(a^x \bmod p)^y \bmod p$ is equal to $a^{xy}\bmod p$.
Does this have a mathematical proof? Please advise.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5366

Comment: @user817536:  I added in the $p$ inside the parentheses.  Please make sure this is what you meant.

Comment: @Ross: Given the original text of the question (in the revision history), I think that's what was intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this was migrated from SO, I suspect that by "$n\bmod m$", you mean the remainder when $n$ is divided by $m$, typically with $0\le n<m$ (possibly negative if $n<0$).  In this interpretation, let's call $n=a^x\bmod p$, which means that $a^x=n+kp$ or $n=a^x-kp$ for some integer $k$ and with $0\le n<p$.  Now (assuming $y$ is an integer), when you take $(a^x\bmod p)^y=n^y=(a^x-kp)^y$ and expand the rightmost expression using the binomial theorem, you'll get $a^{xy}$ plus a whole bunch of terms that have a factor of $p$ and thus don't affect $(a^x\bmod p)^y\bmod p$, so that your end result will be equal to $a^{xy}\bmod p$.

Comment: What other interpretations for `n mod m' are there? (I am interested, not being sarcastic.)

Comment: @Swlabr: I think it's much more common to write something like $(a\equiv b)\mod m$ (read "$a$ is congruent to $b$, mod $m$"), which is equivalent to $m|(a-b)$ (read "$a-b$ is divisible by $m$").  This isn't wholly different from the interpretation I describe for "$n\mod m$" in my answer, but I typically don't see "mod" used in a purely-mathematical context as a binary operator that returns the remainder.

Comment: Perhaps, but it is a more-than-common abuse of notation.

Comment: @Swlabr: Absolutely, and I'd say it's probably the standard interpretation in a programming context (except possibly for the issue of negatives).

Comment: @Isaac: I changed the \mod to \bmod, since that is the version used when we are using it as a binary operator, a common practice in Computer Science.  In principle it improves the spacing.  And it actually does in real LaTeX, though the results here are mixed at best. MathJax, at least on my browser, has many spacing weaknesses.

Comment: @user6312: Ahh!  I didn't know about `\bmod`.  In my browser (Chrome/Mac), it looks a *lot* better (virtually no leading space before it.  Thanks for making that edit.

Comment: @Swlabr: In mathematics 'mod' is syntactically a comparison operator, IOW you can think of it as a function with output type bool(ean). Programmers and engineers use it to indicate the remainder of a division operation with integer parameters. If I write the remainder operation using C-style notation $r\% m$, then mathematicians define 'mod m' to mean $$a\equiv b\pmod m\Leftrightarrow (a\%m)==(b\%m).$$ For the purposes of algebra this notation is more natural, more useful, and more generalizable, when we are dividing other things (e.g. polynomials).

Comment: @Jyrki: That's a good way of putting it.  Just be careful about negative numbers—in some languages, $a<0,m>0\implies -m<a\%m\le0$, for instance.

Comment: @Isaac: Yes. I don't know whether that behavior is defined by the language or the HW, though? At least Intel x86 family of processors took me by surprise here once :-) But your point stands, mod behaves unexpectedly with negative numbers. Why can't the programmers just give up on this, and agree that algebraists' notation is the only way, why, why, why? A pet peeve of mine :-)

Comment: @Jyrki: I have mixed feelings about the notation and terminology, having done lots of both math and programming.  As to the issue of how it's defined on the programming side, it can be language specific, as [C99 and its derivatives, including Objective-C, define $a\%b$ with $a<0$ to be negative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430817#2430817), but sometimes it's implementation-specific.  [The Wikipedia article on the modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is a good source for what symbol and which definition is used in each of a variety of languages.

Answer (score 10):

It's usually simpler to work with congruences rather than the binary $\bmod$ operator, and then go tot he binary operator at the end.

Given an integer $n$, we say that $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ ("$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $n$") if and only if $n$ divides $b-a$. It is easy to show that "congruent modulo $n$" is an equivalence relation; that is, $a\equiv a \pmod{n}$ for every $a$; if $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ then $b\equiv a\pmod{n}$; and if $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $b\equiv c\pmod{n}$, then $a\equiv c\pmod{n}$.

**Proposition.** The following are equivalent:

1. $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$.
2. $n$ divides $a-b$.
3. $a = b+kn$ for some integer $k$.
4. $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$.

*Proof.* (1)$\Leftrightarrow$(2): This is the definition.

(2)$\Rightarrow$(3): Since $n$ divides $a-b$, there exists $k$ such that $nk = a-b$; hence $a=b+nk$, as claimed.

(3)$\Rightarrow$(4). Let $b=qn+r$, with $0\leq r\lt |n|$. Then $a=b+kn = qn+r+kn = (q+k)n+r$, with $0\leq r\lt |n|$. By the uniqueness clause of the [division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Statement_of_theorem), it follows that $r$ is also the remainder of $a$ when divided by $n$.

(4)$\Rightarrow$(2). If $a=qn+r$, $b=pn+r$, $0\leq r\lt|n|$, then $a-b = (q-p)n$, so $n$ divides $a-b$. **QED**

Condition (4) tells you that if you have an equality between expressions involving remainders of numbers, they are equivalent to the corresponding congruence. In your question, this means that the desired equality holds if and only if $a^{xy}$ is congruent to $(a^x)^y$ modulo $n$, which holds because they are in fact equal. But to get it more carefully:

**Corollary.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then every integer $a$ is congruent modulo $n$ to one and only one of $0$, $1$, $2,\ldots,n-1$.

*Proof.* Dividing $a$ by $n$ we have $a = qn + r$, $0\leq r\lt n$. Then $a\equiv r\pmod{n}$; so every integer is congruent to at least one of $0,\ldots,n-1$. For uniqueness, let $i,j$ be integers, $0\leq i,j\leq n-1$ such that $i\equiv j\pmod{n}$. Without loss of generality, assume $i\leq j$. Then $0\leq j-i\lt n$, and $n$ divides $j-i$; the only possibility is for $j-i=0$, so $j=i$. **QED**

**Definition.** Let $a$ be an integer, $n$ a positive integer. We define $a\bmod n$ ("$a$ mod $n$") to be the unique nonnegative integer $i$, $0\leq i\lt n$, such that $a\equiv i\pmod{n}$. That is, $a\equiv (a\bmod n)\pmod{n}$, and $0\leq (a\bmod n)\lt n$.

**Theorem.** If $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{n}$, then $a+c\equiv b+d\pmod{n}$ and $ac\equiv bd\pmod{n}$.

*Proof.* Our hypothesis are that $n$ divides both $a-b$ and $c-d$. Therefore, it divides their sum, $(a+c)-(b+d)$ (which implies $a+c\equiv b+d\pmod{n}$); it also divides $(a-b)c$ and $b(c-d)$; adding these latter two gives that $ac-bd$ is a multiple of $n$, so $ac\equiv bd\pmod{n}$. **QED**

**Corollary.** If $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$, and $r$ is a positive integer, then $a^r\equiv b^r\pmod{n}$.

Now consider $(a^x)^y$ and $a^{xy}$.

Note that $(a^x)^y = a^{xy}$, so $(a^x)^y\equiv a^{xy}\pmod{n}$. Also, since $a^x \equiv (a^x\bmod n)\pmod{n}$, then $(a^x)^y \equiv (a^x\bmod n)^y\pmod{n}$. Since $a^{xy}\equiv (a^x)^y\pmod{n}$, and $(a^x)^y\equiv (a^x\bmod n)^y\pmod{n}$, then $a^{xy}\equiv (a^x\bmod n)^y\pmod{n}$.

And since $a^{xy}\equiv (a^x\bmod n)^y\pmod{n}$, then $a^{xy}$ and $(a^x\bmod n)^y$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$; that is,
$$a^{xy}\bmod n = (a^x\bmod n)^y \bmod n,$$
as desired.

Comment: I've added this question to my favorites just for this explanation.  Thank you for working through it in detail.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for more on the difference between mod as a binary operator vs. ternary congruence.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to prove from first principles that $(a\mod p)(b \mod p) \mod p = (ab)\mod p$ for all integers $a, b$. Now you can prove your statement by induction on $y$.

Comment: In the current context, this is absolutely the right approach, even though translating the problem into language that we mathematicians are more comfortable with, and then translating back, certainly works.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to prove is that if $a \equiv b \mod n$ then $a^m \equiv b^m \mod n$.

While this follows by induction from the product rule as mentined above, you can also prove it directly the following way:

In $n$ divides $a-b$, then $n$ also divides

$$(a-b)[a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+b^{n-1}]= a^n-b^n \,.$$

Comment: The point of using congruences is that we can reuse our arithmetical intuition to make such inferences more evident. Namely, here it's the triviality $\ a\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ a^n\equiv b^n\:,\ $ which is simply a special case of the **congruence product rule**.

Comment: I agree, but to formally prove this trivial implication one usually uses induction, which makes the proof a little more complicated than it needs. Also note that the inductive step is exactly the cancelation in the above telescopic sum. IMO it depends to whom the "proof" is addressed, if it is towards a mathematician/math student yes the product rule is the better approach...... Also I always find it easier to explain to a non-mathematician the product rule the following way:  $a\equiv b \mod n \Rightarrow ax \equiv bx \mod n$...

Comment: Cont.... Then if $ a\equiv b$ and $c  \equiv d$ we have $ac \equiv bc$ and $cb \equiv db$.... It is exactly the same proof, but more intuitive to a non-mathematician  IMO :)

Comment: But the inductive step for $\ a-b\ |\ a^n - b^n\ $ is not as evident as that for $\ a\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ a^n\equiv b^n\ $. Using congruences has the effect of normalising the induction step to an obvious form, here an instance of the product rule. It converts a statement involving divisibility *relations* to a statement involving arithmetical (ring) *operations* - permitting us to use our well-practiced arithmetical skills.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is clearer using congruences vs. normal forms (least remainders). To translate between the two languages note that $\rm\ A\ mod\ m\ =\ a\ mod\ m\ \iff\ A\equiv a\ \ (mod\ m)\:,\:$ i.e. $\rm\ m\ |\ A-a\:.\:$ Now the sought result follows by induction after applying the following ubiquitous

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\ \ A\equiv a,\ B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ AB\equiv ab\ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\:\ \ m\: |\: A-a,\ B-b\:\ \Rightarrow\:\ m\ |\ (A-a)\ B + a\ (B-b)\ =\ AB - ab $