# Proof that $(a\cdot a)\bmod b=\Big((a\bmod b)\cdot(a\bmod b)\Big)\bmod b$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove this kinda of trivial modular attribute, but keep failing.

$$(a\cdot a)\bmod b=\Big((a\bmod b)\cdot(a\bmod b)\Big)\bmod b$$

Any ideas?

Comment: I took the liberty of converting to more standard mathematical notation.

Comment: More generally, $\rm x=an+b$ and $\rm y=cn+d$ yield $$\rm xy=(an+b)(cn+d)=(acn+bc+ad)n+bd$$ Hence $\rm x\equiv b,~y\equiv d\bmod n \implies xy\equiv bd\bmod n$. This holds even if $\rm b,d$ are not chosen among the usual representatives $\rm\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Try to express $a$ as $(b \times k) + c$ and then proceed

Comment: Great, got it..

Answer (score 0):

$a = (a \mod b) \mod b$ and by compatibility with multiplication (by itself) you get $a*a = (a\mod b)*(a \mod b) \mod b$ and since $a*a=((a*a)\mod b) \mod b$ you get your result.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $\rm\,\ a^2\bmod b\ =\, (a\bmod b)^2 \bmod b,\:$ since $\rm\,\ x\equiv y\,\ (mod\ b)\, \Rightarrow\, (x\ mod\ b) = (y\ mod\ b),$

it suffices to prove  $\rm\ \ \ \  a^2 \equiv\ (a\bmod b)^2\ (mod\ b).\ $ But that's  a special case of

$\rm\qquad\qquad\quad mod\ b\!:\,\ \begin{eqnarray} a\,\equiv\, \hat a\\ \rm c\,\equiv\, \hat c\end{eqnarray}\ \Rightarrow\ ac\,\equiv\, \hat a\hat c,\ \ $ the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48027/23500)

**Remark** $\ $ Generally, as above, when proving ring theoretical properties of the *mod operation,* it is simpler, conceptually and computationally, to work with the associated *congruence*  *relation*, i.e. work $\,\rm(mod\ b),\,$ in a *quotient ring*.