# Debug back-substitution in extended Euclidean algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to find the `modular inverse of 28 mod 45` with the Euclidean algorithm but I'm getting the wrong answer. According to online calculators, the answer is $37$, but I'm getting $42$, here are my steps, where am I messing up? Thanks in advance.

Euclidean algorithm:
$$45=28\left(1\right)+17$$

$$28=17\left(1\right)+11$$

$$17=11\left(1\right)+6$$

$$11=6\left(1\right)+5$$

$$6=5\left(1\right)+1$$

Then I rearrange the bottom 3 equations:
$$6-5\left(1\right)=1$$
$$11-6\left(1\right)=5$$
$$17-11\left(1\right)=6$$

Substitute for $5$ in the $6-5(1)=1$ equation:

$$6-\left(11-6\left(1\right)\right)\left(1\right)=1$$
$$6-11+6=1$$
$$2(6)+11(-1)=1$$

And finally, substitute the $6$ to get my answer of $42$:

$$2\left(17-11\left(1\right)\right)+11\left(-1\right)=1$$
$$2\left(17\right)+11\left(-3\right)=1$$
$$45-3\ =\ 42$$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. You are not done yet. You need to arrive at an equation of the form $28s + 45t = 1$ with integers $s$ and $t$. Continue substituting, using all equations,

Comment: @HansEngler oh dang! that's a tedious processes, thank you!

Comment: You want your last part when finding $28s +45t = 1$. So you want to start where you did with $1$ and work backwards to get the $s$ and $t$. You'll see $45t \mod45 \equiv 0 \mod45$, so your inverse will be $s$.

Comment: To avoid such headaches stop doing it backwards! Instead use the simpler [forward form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks for the new approach! though I'm having a difficult time understanding how it looks

Comment: @PSUChange See the last example in my prior link, with the equations listed. What is not clear to you there?

Comment: @BillDubuque  how do you change the numbers from one line to the next? I don't see a relationship. if you could do it with my numbers here that'd be amazing, ill accept it as answer

Comment: The row operations are extensions of the Euclidean algorithm algorithm operations as explained in the [master post linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242), e.g see "for example  $ 62-3(18) = 8$ ..." there.

Comment: @BillDubuque ooh thank you!

Comment: And see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually/85841#comment4931512_85841) there. Is it clear now?  If so you should see how much simpler it is propagating the equations forward vs backward.

Comment: Applied to your problem: $$\rm\begin{eqnarray}
[\![1]\!]\ \ \ \ \, 45\ &=&\,\ \  1&\cdot& 45\, +\ 0&\cdot& 28 \\
[\![2]\!]\ \ \ \ \ 28\ &=&\,\ \  0&\cdot& 45\, +\ 1&\cdot& 28 \\
[\![1]\!]-2\,[\![2]\!]\, \rightarrow\, [\![3]\!]\ \  {-}11\ &=&\,\ \  1&\cdot& 45\, -\ 2&\cdot& 28 \\
[\![2]\!]+2\,[\![3]\!]\,\rightarrow\,[\![4]\!]\quad\ \ \ 6\ &=&\,\ \ 2&\cdot& 45\, -\ 3&\cdot& 28 \\
[\![3]\!]+2\,[\![4]\!]\,\rightarrow\,[\![5]\!]\quad\ \ \ \color{#c00}1\ &=&\,\ \ 5&\cdot& 45\, -\ \color{#0a0}8&\cdot&\color{#0a0}{28}
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: Reducing the prior Bezout equation $\bmod 45\!:\ \color{#c00}1\equiv \color{#0a0}{-8\cdot 28}\,$ so $\,28^{-1}\equiv -8\equiv 37.\,$ Note that we used a smaller negative remainder ($-11$ vs. $17$) in row $ [\![3]\!]$ to shorten work - see [this remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/722205/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque yep! I got it, thank you! it is a easier approach. will save me a lot of time! time to impress my friends lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where does the last line come from. From$$2\times17+(-3)\times11=1,$$you should get that$$2\times17+(-3)\times(28-17)=1,$$or$$5\times17-3\times28=1.$$And now$$5\times(45-28)-3\times28=1,$$or$$5\times45-8\times28=1.$$So, the inverse of $28$ mod $45$ is $-8$, or $37$.

Comment: thanks so much! i'll accept this answer when it allows me

Answer (score 1):

Work backwards as follows:
\begin{align*}
1&=6-5=6-(11-6)\\
&=2\cdot6-11=2\cdot(17-11)-11\\
&=2\cdot17-3\cdot11=2\cdot17-3(28-17)\\
&=5\cdot17-3\cdot28=5\cdot(45-28)-3\cdot28\\
&=5\cdot45-8\cdot28,
\end{align*}
so $28(-8)=1\bmod45$.

Comment: ooooooh, i have continue it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard layout of the *extended Euclidean algorithm*, which yields the coefficients of a Bézout's relation between $28$ and $45$. It uses the fact that  each remainder $r_i$ in the algorithm satisfy a Bézout's relation $\;u_i\, 28+v_i\,45=r_i$ and that these coefficients satisfy the recurrence relation of order $2$
$$u_{i+1}=u_{i-1}-q_iu_i,\qquad v_{i+1}=v_{i-1}-q_iv_i, $$
where $q_i$ is the quotient in the $i$-th division.
\begin{array}{r|rr|l}
r_i&u_i&v_i&q_i \\\hline
45 & 0 & 1 \\
28 & 1 & & 1 \\ \hline
17 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
11 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\
6 & -3 & 2 & 1 \\
5 & 5 & -3 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & \color{red}{-8} & \color {red}5
\end{array}
so the relation is
$$-8\cdot 28+5\cdot 45=1$$
and therefore $\;28^{-1}\bmod 45=-8\equiv 37$.

Answer (score 1):

NOT AN ANSWER BUT FOOD FOR THOUGHT.

Alternatively (although not Euclidean Algorithm exactly):

$28$ goes into $45$, $1$ times with $17$ left over so:  $1\cdot 28 \equiv -17 \pmod {45}$

$17$ goes into $45$, $2$ times with $11$ left over so: $2\cdot 1\cdot 28 \equiv 2(-17)\equiv -34 \equiv 11 \pmod {45}$

$11$ goes inot $44$, $4$ times with $1$ left over so: $4\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 28 \equiv 4\cdot 11 \equiv 44 \equiv -1 \pmod {45}$

So $-4\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 28 \equiv 1\pmod 45$

And $-4 \cdot 2 \cdot 1\equiv -8\equiv 37 \equiv 28^{-1} \pmod {45}$.

This differs from the classical Euclidean Algorithm in that the remainder always divides into the original modulus rather than the previous quotient.  Has an advantage that you you have a straight product which is easier to calculate than a seriers of sums and products.  Not sure why this isn't done more or why I never noticed it before.

... oh, I guess I see the bug....

Consider

$28 \equiv -17 \pmod {45}$

$3\cdot 28 \equiv -51 \equiv -6\pmod {45}$

$21 \cdot 28 \equiv -42 \equiv 3 \pmod {45}$

$(15\cdot 21)\cdot 28 \equiv 45 \equiv 0 \pmod {45}$

And $15\cdot 21 \equiv 45 \cdot 7 \equiv 0\pmod {45}$.

By dividing into the original modulus we make no assurance that the remainders are relatively prime to the original modulus.

We can make a rule that you only multiply be terms relatively prime to the modulus but that defeats the original purpose of EA to find out what *is* the gcd of terms.

Still as we know $45 = 5\times 3^2$ and $\gcd(28, 45)=1$ this is easy to work.  Of course if you have an number lots of factors, say $360$, the the rule, don't multiply by any multiple of $2,3,5$ makes this method impractical.....

Oh, well.  I thought it worked so well......