# Can you solve a diophantine equation considering negative remainders in the GCD step?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

To solve the following equation $$32x - 18y = 40$$,
I first found the GCD like that:
$$32 = (-18)(-1) + 14 $$
$$-18 = (14)(-1) - 4 $$
$$14 = (-4)(-3) + 2 $$
$$-4 = (2)(-2) + 0 $$

Therefore, I found 2.
But these negative values are confusing, because I don't know if they are allowed there, even though I can find a solution to the equation if I proceed with the calculations:

$$ 2 = (14) - (-4)(-3) $$
$$ 2 = (14) - (-18-14(-1))(-3) $$
$$ 2 = (14) - 18(3)+14(3) $$
$$ 2 = (32-(-18)(-1)(4)) - (18)(3) $$
$$ 2 = 32(4) - (-18)(-4) - (18)(3) $$
$$ 2 = 32(4) - (18)(7) $$
$$ 40 = 32(80) - (18)(140) $$
Therefore, I have $$x_0 = 80, y_0 = 140$$ as particular solution,
and $$x = 80 + 9n, y = 140 + 16n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
as a complete solution.

Comment: Yes, you can use least magnitude (possibly negative) remainders in the extended Euclidean algorithm, e.g. see the Remark  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) in the linked dupe. This can [halve the number of steps](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/722205/242). Another great optimization is to stop doing it *backwards* and instead use the easier *forward* method described there (or - even quicker - the *fractional* method described there).

Comment: Generally we can use any [gcd mod reduction steps](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242), i.e. $(a,b) = (a'
,b)\,\ {\rm  if}\,\ a\equiv a
'\pmod{\! b},\,$ as long as they *eventually* reach a "simpler" gcd, where simpler need not necessarily mean smaller magnitude argument, e.g here is an *increasing* step $\,(319,705) = (319,\color{#c00}{319+705}) = (319,\color{#c00}{2^{10}}) = 1.\ \ $

Comment: e.g. $\!\bmod 18\!:\ x \equiv \dfrac{40}{32}\!\!\overset{\div\,2\!}\iff\! \bmod 9\!:\ x \equiv \dfrac{20}{16}\equiv \dfrac{10}{8}\equiv \color{#c00}{\dfrac{1}{-1}},\,$ so $\,x = \color{#c00}{-1}+9k,\,$ so $\, y = \dfrac{-40+32x}{18} = \dfrac{-72+32(9k)}{18} = -4+16k.\,$ Your solution shifts the parameter  $\, k = 9+n.\ \ $

Comment: Easier: $\,8\mid 18y\Rightarrow 4\mid y\,$ so cancel $4\Rightarrow 8x-18(y/4)=10\,$ with obvious root $\,x=-1=y/4\ \ $