# How to calculate mod inverse

Tags: number-theory

Given a number set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$, how do I find the inverse of a given number?

I am trying to test an algorithm to extract the $k$ and $x$ values from the Elgamal Signature algorithm given that $k$ is repeated.

What I have is
$k$ congruent to $(m_1 - m_2)\times(s_1 - s_2)^{-1} \mod p - 1$
given $k$ is used twice.

I am not sure how to calculate the mod inverse though?
_
Is the above formula the same thing as $((m_1 - m_2) \mod p -1 \times  (s_1 - s_2)^{-1} \mod p -1) \mod p -1$

I am not sure if it is any different since I am doing a mod inverse.

PS. I am a programmer, not a mathematician so please elaborate.

Comment: Use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163107/242)

Comment: I know how to find a mod inverse. But if I have a number A*B^-1 mod p-1 is that equivalent to A mod p-1 * B mod p-1 mod p-1. That is what I found online but I wasn't sure.

Comment: $ab$ is invertible $\iff a,b$ are invertible $\iff a,b\,$ are coprime to the modulus. When so we have $(ab)^{-1}\equiv b^{-1}a^{-1}\,$ by $\ b^{-1}a^{-1} (ab) \equiv b^{-1}(a^{-1}a)b\equiv b^{-1}b \equiv 1\ $ (inverses are always unique)

Comment: So what if I have a number * an inverse mod p -1. How would I break that down?

Comment: Calculate the inverse then modular_multiply the two as you would any pair of (modular) integers - using the [mod prodcut rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890405/product-rule-for-the-mod-operator/1890422?s=1|88.8095#1890422)

Comment: If you seek a rigorous prove it then you'll also need to show $\, A\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, A^{-1}\equiv a^{-1},\,$ asumming that $\gcd(a,n) = 1\ [\!\iff \gcd(A,n) = 1,\,$ by $\,A\equiv a\pmod{\!n}]$

Comment: I think this should be good I am just trying to show how to retrieve the private exponent of ElGamal signature when k is repeated. Which has me trying to calculate an example using the formula in the question.

Comment: In summary, you can mod the argument of the inverse operation just as you do for arguments of sums and products. But *beware* that you can't do that for exponents (though exponents  can  be modded out by the *order* of the base, when it is invertible, or by any other power $k$ such that $a^k\equiv 1$, e.g. as in Fermat or Euler's theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two formulas you wrote in the question give the same output.

More generally, as Bill Dubuque points out in the comments, you can usually just take mods at each step, instead of doing the whole computation and then modding at the end. However, exponentiation is a notable exception; you can reduce the *base* but generally not the *exponent*
$$ a^k \bmod n  \quad=\quad (a\bmod n)^k \bmod n \qquad\neq\qquad (a\bmod n)^{(k \bmod n)}.$$

Comment: This answer exists primarily to remove this question from the Unanswered list; please upvote (or give Best Answer) to complete the process.