# How can I prove (a * b) mod c = (a mod c * b mod c) mod c?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I got this solution when was reading a book about competitive programming to avoid mod calculus with very large numbers. But I would like to know why it's trustworthy.

Comment: Write $a$ as $xc+v$ and $b$ as $yc+w$ where $0 \le v < c$ and  $0 \le w < c$.  Then both sides are equivalent to  $v  w \mod c$

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1890422/242) in the 2nd linked dupe for the *easy* way to prove this.