# Prove $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is divisible by $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \equiv 0\pmod d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I'm not sure how to prove $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is divisible by $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \equiv o \pmod d$

I get that I have to prove the cases of (1) if $d\mid n$ then $n\equiv 0 \pmod d$, and (2) if $n\equiv 0 \pmod d$, then $d\mid n$.  But I don't know how to prove them.
So, what's the proof for case 1? I think I can figure out 2 from there.

Comment: How did you define $n \mod d=0$? If you can write down the definition of that maybe you will figure out what to do next.

Comment: What is your definition of n mod d = x?  The usual one is that $d$ divides $n - x$ in which case with $x=0$ it is trivial.

Comment: n mod d = r and n = dq + r, so if r = 0 n = dq?

Comment: Yes that looks right.

Comment: By [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/614931/242) $\,n\equiv 0\pmod{d}\iff d\mid  n-0 = n\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

One says that $n \pmod{d} = r$ when $ n = q d + r $ for some integer $q$ and $r \in \{0,\dots, d-1\}$.
Thus, $r=0$ means  $ n = q d $, which is just another way of saying that $d$ divides $n$.

Comment: But OP did not once use the notation “$n\pmod d=r$”. Instead, OP used the notation “$n\equiv0\pmod d$” .

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to state the definition of $a≡b($mod $m)$

As first used by Gauss, the above notation implies that $$m|a-b$$

Now as you mentioned, the question says $n≡0($mod $d)$

$\implies d|n-0$
$\implies d|n$

which I think provides the answer to part $(ii)$ of your question

Now, you can easily solve part $(i)$ as well using the definition of congruence.