# Cannot understand congruence relation from RSA

Tags: congruences, cryptography

Currently I'm reading about RSA and have a trouble understanding the following formula:
$$e \cdot d \equiv 1 (\mod (p-1)(q-1))  $$
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) I know that for a given positive integer $n$, two integer $a$ and $b$ are called congruent modulo $n$ if $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$.
But! If you take a reminder of $1$ divided but any $n>1$, the remainder will be $1$. That is, we can simplify he first formula to be:
$$(e \cdot d) \mod ((p-1)(q-1)) = 1 $$
Are these formulas equivalent?

Comment: These are two ways of writing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that second thing doesn't mean anything in standard mathematical notation. However, partly because of exposure to programming, people will know what you intend by the second thing. And the two meanings are equivalent. (The reason is that $1$ is less than $(p-1)(q-1)$, so when you divide it by $(p-1)(q-1)$ you just get $1$ back as the remainder.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a \equiv b\pmod n\,$ means $\,n\mid a-b,\ $ i.e. $\,a-b = nk,\,$ for some integer $k$.

$(a\bmod n) = b\ $ means the above *plus* $\,0\le b < n,\,$ i.e. $\,b\,$ is the least natural $\equiv a\pmod n$ or, equivalently, $\,b\,$ is the remainder left when dividing $\,a\,$ by $\,n.\,$

In your case $\,b = 1 < n\,$ is always true  so they are always equivalent. But for larger $\,b\,$ this is not true, e.g. $\, 0 \equiv 2\pmod 2\,$ but $\,(0\bmod 2)\ne 2.$

Congruence *relations* are often more convenient for theory, whereas normal forms (such as produced by the mod *operator*) are often more convenient for computation. But it is best to be proficient with the use of both, and to be able to quickly convert back-and-forth between the two as need be.

Comment: **Note** $\ $ Above I presume the typical convention that the modulus $\,n\ge 2\,$ in elementary number theory. Later in  algebra it will prove  convenient to also alllow moduli (ideals) that are $0$ or $1.\ $

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for much more on this and related topics. $\ \ $