# Why $(a^n X_i)\bmod m = ((a^n \bmod m) X_i) \bmod m$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've seen similar posts here asking why $(ab)\bmod m = (a \bmod m)( b \bmod m)$, but none of them really answers my question or gives a detailed the mathematical proof.

I know that $a\equiv b \pmod m$, $c\equiv d \pmod m)$ implies $ac\equiv bd \pmod m$, and I was going to approach this by setting $a = k_am + a \pmod m$ and $b = k_bm + b \pmod m$ then multiply $a$ and $b$, but I got stuck.

Comment: By  said congruence product rule, and $\,(a^n\bmod m)\equiv a^n\pmod m,\,$ you know they are congruent, say $y \equiv y'\pmod{m}.\,$ So it suffces to show that this implies $\,(y\bmod m) = (y'\bmod m),\,$ i.e. congruent integers have the same remainder. Do you see how to do that? [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3173344/242) for another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a definition, you want define a product on $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ but you have only a product on $\mathbb{Z}$. A way to define  product on  $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$  it is to prove that

if $a\cong c$ mod $m $ and $b\cong d$ mod m then

$ab\cong cd $ mod $m$ so it is well define the following operation on $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ :

($a$ mod $m$)($b$ mod $m$):= $ab$ mod $m$$