# Why does $(g^b \bmod m)^a \bmod m = (g^a \bmod m)^b \bmod m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography

I have been trying to understand why the Diffie Dellman key exchange algorithm works, specifically why the two exponents can be swapped in it without the result changing.

So my specific question is why:

$$\begin{align} &(g^b \bmod m)^a \bmod  m\\
=\ &(g^a \bmod m)^b \bmod m\end{align}\qquad$$

I am interested in the reasoning/proof/explanation behind why it is true.

I am completely aware that it can be proved from common rules of modular arithmetic, but I am asking for a detailed proof/explanation for why it holds true  as at least for me the proof isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: basic exponent rules that's why.

Comment: See edited question, to clarify. @roddy macphee

Comment: it's literally that most common arithmetic rules don't break in mod, they just get reduced ahead of time $$(g^a)^b=g^{ab}=g^{ba}=(g^b)^a $$ is one such combination of rules.

Comment: Yes I am completely aware that it is a common rule, but I am asking for a proof/explanation for why it holds true in modular arithmetic as at least for me the proof isn't immediately obvious. Thank you

Comment: because mod is defined as $$y\equiv b\mod m\iff y=mx+b$$ for integer values for all variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, to prove an equality about mod as an *operation* it is usually easiest to convert it into an equivalent but more flexible *congruence relation* form, via the following equivalence (cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242))

$$  (g\bmod m) = (h\bmod m)\color{#c00}\iff g\equiv h\!\!\!\pmod {\!m}\qquad $$

$\begin{align}
{\rm so}\ \ \ (g^b\bmod m)^a\bmod m &= (g^a \bmod m)^b\bmod m\\[.2em]
\color{#c00}\iff (g^b\bmod m)^a &\equiv (g^a \bmod m)^b \!\!\!\pmod{\!m}\\[.2em]
\iff (g^b)^a &\equiv (g^a)^b\!\!\! \pmod{\!m}\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#0a0}{\rm CPR}\ \ \color{#c00}{\&}\ \ g^{n}\bmod m\equiv g^n\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}
\end{align}$

that's true by $\,(g^b)^a = g^{ab} = (g^a)^b\,$ by integer power laws. Here  $\color{#0a0}{\rm CPR} = $ [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

**Key Idea** $ $ Generally, as above, using the above equivalence and congruence laws, we can erase all $\!\bmod m$  *operations* in a *polynomial* expression (i.e. where mod  appears in arguments of sums & products, but *not* in exponents) to obtain an equivalent congruence, e.g. for the above

$$\begin{align}(\color{#c00}{g^b\color{#bbb}{\bmod m})^a\color{#bbb}{\bmod m}} \,&=\, \color{#0a0}{(g^a \color{#bbb}{\bmod m})^b\color{#bbb}{\bmod m}}\\[.2em]
\iff \color{#c00}{(g^b)^a} &\equiv\, \color{#0a0}{(g^a)^b}\!\!\pmod{\!m}
\end{align}\qquad$$

Since congruence arithmetic inherits all common (ring) arithmetic laws (commutative, associative, distributive), it is much easier to use our well-honed *arithmetical* (vs. divisibility) intuition to prove congruence equations than it is to prove the equivalent divisibility statements.

**Generally**, as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3173344/242), in any polynomial expression of integers, i.e, an expression composed of sum and product operations on integers, by inductively applying the congruence sum and product rules we obtain a congruent expression if we replace the arguments of sums and products by congruent integers. Above is a special case: replace *all* $\,a\bmod m\,$ by $\,a$.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense 

Comment: @BillDubuque This, like basically all of your answers I've read, is well done.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: all the usual rules of arithmetic are true for calculations modulo $m$.

That means addition and multiplication are commutative and associative and multiplication distributes over addition. The laws of exponents follow.

You have to be a little more careful trying to think about division.

The proofs are standard material in any elementary number theory text.

Comment: Hmm yeah I am self teaching myself this topic and haven't yet seen a proof for why this is true. Could you link to one (a proof) that you know of? As that is what I am interested in, despite knowing that it works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic or https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic or https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction or https://brilliant.org/wiki/modular-arithmetic/ or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularArithmetic.html etc.

Comment: @DistributedBit I just posted a formal proof. If anything is not clear please feel welcome to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:
The reason why

`(g^b mod m)^a mod m`

`= (g^a mod m)^b mod m`

Is because:

`(g^b mod m)^a mod m` can be simplified to:
`(g^b)^a mod = g^(ba)`

This is because the mod n in the brackets doesn't change the equivalence class of what is being exponentiated to a and multiplying two numbers of the same equivalence class by themselves a certain number of times will result in the same product.

As a result of this, the equation can be represented as `g^(ba) mod m = g^(ab) mod m` which is obviously true because the product ab is the same either way so the exponent is the same.

Comment: @ethan bolker this is what I meant :)

Comment: @roddy macphee this is what I meant :)