# Proofs using modular arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In my textbook, it says,

> The sum of the cubes of any three consecutive integers is divisible by
> $9$

This statement is equivalent to proving,

> $(n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 ) \mod 9 =0$  is true for $n=0,1, \ldots, 8$

Now I understand how the modulo function works but I just don't see how the latter part is the same as the former. Can anyone walk me through it?

Note that, I'm not really looking for the proof, what I am looking for is **how** the first and the second statement are related.

Follow up question which begs to be asked,

Given some expression of $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, say $P(a)$, are the following 2 statements equivalent?

1. $n$ divides $P(a), \, \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and for some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $P(a) \mod n = 0, \forall a \in \{0,1, \ldots, n-1\}$

Can anyone explain me whether or not the two statements are equivalent? Thanks!

Comment: When you typed $P(a)$ divides $n$, did you mean $n$ divides $P(a)$?  That is equivalent to $P(a)\equiv0\pmod n$

Comment: Cf. the [polynomial congruence rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879251/divisibility-by-7-rule-and-congruence-arithmetic-laws/879262#879262)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oopsy, my bad. I was actually going to write $P(a)$ is divisible by $n$

Comment: This problem has been discussed here many times, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6814/242).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Given some expression of $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, say $P(a)$, are the following 2 statements equivalent?
>
> 1. $n$ divides $P(a), \, \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and for some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$
> 2. $P(a) \bmod n = 0, \forall a \in \{0,1, \ldots, n-1\}$

Yes, let's derive the equivalence step-by-step.

$$\begin{align}
\forall\, a\,\in\, \Bbb Z:&\ \ \ n\,\mid\, P(a)\\[.2em]
\iff \forall\, a\,\in\, \Bbb Z:&\ \ \ 0 = P(a)\bmod n\\[.2em]
\iff \forall\, a\,\in\, \Bbb Z:&\ \ \ 0 = P(\bar a)\bmod n,\,\ \bar a = a\bmod n, \ \rm by\ \color{#C00}{PCR}\\[.2em]
\iff \forall\, \bar a\in[n]\!:&\ \ \ 0 = P(\bar a)\bmod n,\,\ [n] = \{0,1,\ldots,n\!-\!1\}\\[.2em]
\iff \forall\, \bar a\in\Bbb Z_n\!:&\ \ \ 0 = P(\bar a)
\end{align}\qquad$$

where we employed the following [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\, =\rm\color{#C00}{PCR}$

$\quad \bmod n\!:\ a\equiv \bar a\,\Rightarrow\, P(a)\equiv P(\bar a),\ $ for $\,P(x)\,$ any polynomial with *integer* coef's

[Generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3467207/242), given any expression composed of sums and products of integers, its value  $\bmod n\,$ is unchanged when we replace the arguments of the sums and products by congruent arguments.  In particular this is true if we replace them by their least nonnegative reps $\, a\mapsto a\bmod n$.

Above we could replace the standard residue system $\,[n] = 0,1,2,\ldots\,n\!-\!1\,$ by any *complete* system of residues $\cal R,\,$ i.e. any set of integers such that every integer is congruent to exactly one $\,r\in \cal R.\,$ Then verifying that every $\,r\in\cal R\,$ is a root is sufficient to guarantee that every integer is a root, since every integer is congruent to some normal rep $\,r\in\cal R,\,$ i.e. we have $\,n\equiv r\in {\cal R}\,\Rightarrow\, P(n)\equiv P(r)\equiv 0,\,$ by $\,\rm\color{#c00}{PCR}$

A "normal" rep in $\cal R$ can be view as "name' or "label" for the *entire* set of integers equivalent to it, i.e. $\,r\mapsto [r]_n = r + n\Bbb Z,\,$ the set of all integers $\equiv r\pmod{\!n}.\,$ Then the congruence sum and product rules imply that addition and multiplication is well-defined on these classes by the rules $[a]+[b] = [a+b],\,$ $[a]*[b] = [a*b].\,$ In turn this implies that the arithmetical (ring) laws of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ are inherited by the classes with these operations, so they form a new system of numbers (ring) $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ sharing many of the same properties of the ring of integers - so we can *reuse* our well-honed integer arithmetic intuition in this new modular number system. In particular, viewed in the ring $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ your statement simplifies to the final form in the string of equivalences, viz. $\,\forall\,\bar a \in \Bbb Z_n\!:\ P(\bar a) = 0,\,$ i.e. every element of $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ is a root of $\,P\,$ (here $P$ is viewed as a polynomial over $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ by mapping its integer coef's into $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ via $\,p_i\mapsto \bar p_i = [p_i]_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ n | P(a) \ \forall \ a\in \mathbb Z \iff P(a) \mod n = 0 \ \forall \ a\in \{0,1,2\dots n-1\}$$ The key here is that if all elements $e$ in this set satisfy this property, then all numbers of the form $e+nk$ for some integer $k$ also satisfy this property, as the $kn$ term gets vanished mod $n$. For instance, $$ n^3 +(n+1)^3 +(n+2)^3 \equiv (n+9k)^3 +(n+9k+1)^3 +(n+9k+2)^3 \pmod 9 $$ because $$(n+9k)^3 = n^3 +9^3k^3 +3n^2(9k) +3(n)(9^2k^2) = n^3 +9(\text{stuff}) $$ and similarly for the other two terms.

Comment: There was a big typo, I meant to wrote $n| P(a)$, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @William I noticed! Hence the first line in my answer. No worries.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. After scribbling around a little. I think I get it. Let me put this into my words. So given a polynomial in $a$, i.e. $P(a)$ we can show that $P(a)$ is divisible by $n$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ by showing/checking that $n|P(a)$ for every $a \in S = \{0,1, \ldots n-1 \}$ because any integer $a$ can be expressed as $nq+r$ with $r \in S$ and the fact that $P(r) \equiv P(nk + r) \mod n$ since $P(nk+r)$ contains all terms of the form $Ar^n$ or $B(nk)$ for integers $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @William Correct.

Comment: Where you hiding, downvoters? What’s wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ and $m$ are equivalent modulo $9$, then so are $n^3$ and $m^3$. Hence there is no need to try all $n$, but only those that yield different values modulo $9$.

Answer (score 0):

$3$ consecutive numbers gives remainders $0,1,-1(i.e 2)$ in some order when divided by $3$. So let $3$ consecutive  numbers be $3k,3k'+1,3k''-1$ in some order. Cubing and adding we get, $(3k)^3+(3k'+1)^3+ (3k''-1)^3= 27k^3+27k'^3+ 9k'^2+ 9k'+1+27k''^3- 9k''^2+ 9k''-1= 9K$

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I was not looking for the proof. I mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for not seeing that.