# Proving modular arithmetic property over large sums

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can I prove that:

$$ ((a + b)\bmod{2} \; + \;c)\bmod{2} = (a+b+c)\bmod{2} $$

I am unsure of the name of this property, but I realized I know this by intuition. The reason for this is that I want to take a sum over $\mathbb{F_2}$ and I would like to say that

$$
(\sum_{i}^{} a_i)\bmod{2}
$$

will suffice, as opposed to taking individual modulus of every addition operation.

Comment: My question is not answered by the linked posts. I would like a proof of the above.

Comment: As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3467207/242) in the linked dupes,  by the Congruence Sum & Product rules, we obtain a congruent expression by replacing aguments of sums & products by *any* congruent argument , e.g. $\,n,\to n\bmod 2\,$ or reversely).

Comment: As explained there, your $\!\bmod 2$ equality is equivalent to  $\,\color{#c00}{(a+b)\bmod 2}+ c\equiv a+b+c\pmod{\!2},$ which follows by replacing the summand $\,\color{#c00}{(a+b)\bmod 2}\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{a+b},\,$ which is valid since, again, they are congruent $\!\pmod{\!2}\ \ $

Answer (score -2):

You can instead prove it on two variables first that, $$(a+b(\mod 2))\mod 2) \equiv a(\mod2)+b(\mod2)$$

After that you can assume $z=a+b$ and reuse your proof on $z$ and $c$. This holds true for any number of variables.

Comment: How can you prove the modulus is distributable?

Comment: Sorry I have corrected it.

Comment: How do you prove it? That is still not answered.