# solve for $20x+15 \equiv 47 \pmod{4},$ if there are no solution why?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

solve for $20x+15 \equiv 47 \pmod{4},$ if there are no solution why?

I tried to do it the following way, but i'm wondering if it is the way it should be done. Is it correct?

$$20x+15 \equiv 47 \pmod{4},$$

subtract $15$ from $47$,

$$20x \equiv 32\pmod{4},$$

divide both sides by $4$,

$$5x \equiv 8\pmod{4},$$

$$x \equiv 0.$$

Comment: $20x \equiv 32 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ which is trivially true no matter what $x$ is, so any $x$ is a solution. If you divide by $4$, you get $5x \equiv 8 \pmod{1}$ (don't forget to simplify the modulus) which is also true for any integer $x$

Comment: Your analysis is wrong because in the integers mod $4$, you’re not allowed to divide by $4 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Generally you can only scale (and cancel) equations )or congruences) by *invertible* factors if you wish to get an *equivalent* congruence (with same modulus) - see the linked dupes, which also explain general methods to solve linear congruences.

Comment: Reducing mod $4\,$ we get $\,\color{#c00}{20}\:\!x\equiv_4 \color{#0a0}{32}\iff \color{#c00}0\:\!x\equiv_4 \color{#0a0}0$ which is true for all integers $x$. Generally you should reduce all integer arguments of sums & products (but not expts!) by the modulus since it usually simplifes modular arithmetic (this is a valid transformation [due to the Congruence Sum & Product Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3173344/242)).

Answer (score 2):

Since subtraction is a reversible step in modular arithmetic, your first and second equivalences have the same set of solutions.

Then we have $20x \equiv 32 \pmod {4} \Longleftrightarrow 4|(20x-32) 
\Longleftrightarrow 4|4(5x-8)$ which is trivially true for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Every integer modulo $4$ is $0, 1, 2$ or $3$. Plugging $0,1,2,3$ we get $20*0+15=15\equiv 47 \mod 4$, $20*1+15=35\equiv 47 \mod 4$,
$20*2+15=55\equiv 47 \mod 4$, $20*3+15=75\equiv 47 \mod 4$, so every $x$ satisfies your equation. Answer: every integer
$x$.