# I need clarification on modulus regarding congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Saying ***a* is equivalent *b* mod *m*** is like saying:

***a* = *b* - *qm***

where **q** is the quotient, **m** is the divisor, and *a* will equal the remainder. ^ Verify the above statement

So then if we were to solve this equation for *qm* we would get:

***a*-*b*=-*qm***

This logic is contradicted by my professor when looking at one of his proof examples where he states *a* = *b* mod *m* implies a *q* exists such that:

***a-b=qm***

The contradiction is ***qm*** is not negative. I understand this has something to do with congruence, but I am not quite understanding how this is correct and where my logic is flawed.

Comment: The sign of $q$ is irrelevant.  Writing $a\equiv b\pmod m$ is the same as writing $b\equiv a \pmod m$.

Comment: It is as if your naming a new number $q'=-q$ and then writing $a-b=q'm$

Comment: Congruence (residue) arithmetic focuses on the arithmetic of residue classes (remainders) modulo $m$. The quotients $q$ play no essential role in this arithmetic. The sooner you learn to forget about the quotients the quicker you will be able to grasp the essence of the matter.

Comment: a = b mod m means that a -  b is divisible by m.   It is a relation between two numbers.  b mod m is not an operation between two numbers as programmers delude themselves.

Comment: @WilliamElliot  Both the congruence relation $\ a\equiv b\pmod{m}\ $ and remainder operation $\ b \bmod m\ $  are in wide use (in both Math & CS).  Which proves best depends on the context. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for more.