# An intuitive explanation of the multiplication identity of modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there any intuitive explanation for the validity of this identity?

> If $a\equiv b\pmod n$ and $c\equiv d\pmod n$, then
> $$a\times c \equiv b\times d \pmod n$$

I want something which appeals to someone's who just beginning to learn number theory.

Comment: Please cite or describe the unenlightening proof so we don't have to *guess* what would be more enlightening.

Comment: Please also give some background, e.g. do you know any ring theory, e.g. quotient rings such as $\,\Bbb Z_n \cong \Bbb Z\bmod n,\,$ and $\,R[x]/x\cong R$? $\ \ \ $

Comment: The identity is just saying if you multiply two numbers together and take the remainder in terms of $n$, the resulting remainder will be the same as if you had multiplied any other set of  two numbers with the same remainders.  Is that not intuitive?

Answer (score 2):

This is not difficult to prove and understand. The idea is to use a simpler result two times.

> If $a\equiv b\pmod{n} $ then we have $ka\equiv kb\pmod{n} $.

This should be obvious to understand as it is an immediate consequence of the definition of congruence. Just note that if $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$ then $k(a-b) $ is also a multiple of $n$.

Using this we can multiply first congruence with $c$ and second congruence with $b$ to get $$ac\equiv bc\pmod{n}, bc\equiv bd\pmod {n} $$ and these two give you $ac\equiv bd\pmod{n} $ (this is based on the fact that *if two numbers are multiple of $n$ then so is their sum*).

---

I don't think the above would count as *a lot of hairy algebra* and ideally should be accessible to anyone who has basic idea of factors and multiples (typically 6th standard math suited for children of 10-11 years in Indian curriculum).

Answer (score 1):

$a \equiv a'\pmod n$ means that $a$ and $b$ have the same remainders in terms of $n$.

The this identity says that if you have two pairs of numbers $a \equiv a' \pmod n$ and $b\equiv b' \pmod n$ so $a$ and $a'$ have the same remainder and if $b\equiv b' \pmod n$ so $b$ and $b'$ have the same remainder, then the pair of products $ab$ and $a'b'$ will be so that $ab \equiv a'b'$ and the pair of products $ab$ and $a'b'$ will have the same remainder.

That should intuitively obvious.

But if not:

$a$ and $a'$ having the same remainder means $a = kn + r$ for some integer $q$ and $r$ is the remainder and $a' = jn + r$ for a different integer $j$ but the same remainder $r$.

And $b$ and $b'$ having the same remainder means $b = wn + s$ for some integer $w$ and remainder $s$.  And $b' = vn + s$ for a different integer $v$ but the same remainder $s$.

If you muliply $ab$ you get $kvn^2 + kns + vnr + sr=n\cdot (kvn+ks +vr) + sr$.  SO $ab$ will have whatever remainder that $sr$ will have. And if you multiply $a'b'$ you get $jwn^2 +jnr + wnr + sr = n\cdot(jwn+jr + wr) + sr$.  And $a'b'$ will *also* have whatever remainder that $sr$ will have.

So $ab$ and $a'b'$ will both have the same remainder in terms of $n$>

Comment: No, $\,a\equiv a'\pmod{\!n}\,$ "means" $\,n\mid a-a'.\,$ While this turns out to be *equivalent* to $\,a\bmod n = a'\bmod n,\,$ if one takes it to "mean" that instead then it will greatly stunt one's number theoretical growth. @OP See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for more on this.