# Modular arithmetic : Distributive

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I was checking some websites about modular arithmetic, and i read this :

**(x + y) % n = (x % n) + (y % n)**

Is this correct ?

What if we take : x = 4, y = 2, n = 5 ?
We will have 1 = 6 !?

Comment: $1\equiv 6 \mod 5$

Comment: When working in modulo 5, $1\equiv 6$. So you have to see this through the "modular" lenses ...

Comment: The confusion stems from the fact that the operator $\%$ is not used consistently.  Some people use $a\%n$ to refer to the residue class $a\pmod n$  Others use it to refer to the remainder you get on dividing $a$ by $n$.  These are closely related notions, clearly, but they are not the same.

Comment: @WassimJaoui That's precisely what Wuestenfux said.

Comment: @MattiP. this means there's no difference between (x % n) + (y % n) and ((x % n) + (y % n)) %n ? When we are talking about residue class ( modified comment )

Answer (score 1):

Correct is

$(x + y) \div n = [(x \div n) + (y \div n)] \div n$.

Comment: So what i wrote is false, or the annotation is different ?

Comment: Oh i got it ! so this is in the case of modular and not the rest of the division. Because i thought they were the same

Comment: @WassimJaoui No, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for more on the relation between $\!\bmod\!\!,\,$ remainder and %.