# Why is $(k L - y) \mod L = L - y \mod L$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is $(k L - y) \mod L = (L - y) \mod L$? What's the rule that allows the constant $k$ to be ignored?

Comment: [$ a\bmod L = b\bmod L \iff a\equiv b\pmod{\!L}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242), i.e. $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ have equal remainders when divided by $L$ iff $\,a-b\,$ is divisible by $L$ (true here where $\,a-b = kL-y - (L-y) = (k\!-\!1)L)\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your notation $a\pmod b = c\pmod b$ means that $a-c \pmod p =0 \pmod p$ this is just a consequence of the division algorithm. By doing that, notice that the $-y$ cancel and you end up having a $(k-1)\cdot L \pmod L,$ what is the remainder by dividing a number by itself? **hint:** $L = 1\cdot L +0.$

Comment: It doesn't "mean that". Rather, it can be proved to be equivalent to that - see my comment on the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque I know, but throwing equivalences to a coder was an overkill from my perspective.

Comment: But "means" is so imprecise that it often leads to errors, e.g. its denotation could be "by definition"  or it could denote a (uni or bi)directional implication, etc.  Here it is easy to be precise so there is no reason not to be.

Comment: @BillDubuque I agree with that. I will try to improve. Thanks!