# Why is it that $a\equiv b \pmod{m} \iff m|(a-b)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, definition

Why is it that $a\equiv b \pmod m \iff m\mid(a-b)$? I know this is a definition, but it's a definition I don't understand.
I know that if $m\mid(a-b)$ then there exists some $q\in\mathbb Z$ such that $mq=a-b$.

But when I take $a\equiv b \bmod m$ I obtain $b=mq+a$, solving for $mq$ I get $mq=b-a$ instead of $mq=a-b$.

Am I getting something wrong about what $a\equiv b\pmod m$ means? My understanding says $b$ is a dividend, $m$ is a divisor, and $a$ is a remainder. The devision algorithm says dividend${}=(\text{divisor}\times\text{quotient})+\text{remainder},$ so that's how I get $b=mq+a$.

Comment: What is $q$? $~~$

Comment: In general, if $m\mid x$ then $m\mid -x$ as well.

Comment: I've always viewed q as a quotient

Comment: Sometimes you will see a binary "mod" operator, $x \bmod y,$ which means the remainder after $x$ is divided by $y.$ But when you see $\pmod m$ in parentheses, usually the person writing it was not thinking of the binary operator. Usually $a\equiv b\pmod m$ and $b\equiv a\pmod m$ are meant to be equivalent and interchangeable, just like $x=y$ and $y=x$.

Comment: You may note that $a\equiv b\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$ and $b\equiv a\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$ are the same thing.

Comment: What do you think about this: $6\equiv10\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$, Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, $a\equiv b\pmod m$ doesn't mean that $b$ is a dividend, $m$ is a divisor, and $a$ is a remainder. It means the the divisions of $a$ and $b$ by $m$ have the same remainders.

And if $q$ is such that $mq=a-b$, then $m\times(-q)=b-a$.

Comment: (@Lex_i **Beware** that the above answer is conceptually incorrect. The definition of congruence does not "mean" anything about rermainders (though it does have an equivalent forumulation in terms of remainders in any ring which has a division algorithm). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for more on the relationshup between congruence relations and normal form operations