# Finding all solutions for congurence when m equals $2$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am reading the following exercise:

> Find all solutions to the congruence $3x \equiv 5 \mod m $ when $m$
> equals $2$

The solution states:

> Since $3 \equiv 5 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ the congruence is equivalent to $x \equiv 1 \mod 2$. There is one solution which is $x \equiv 1 \mod 2$

The problem I have is I don't really understand the specific steps taken to find the solution.
I understand that:
$3x \equiv (3 \mod m)\cdot (x \mod m)$, I also know that $3x - 5$ is a multiple of $m$ but I am not sure what (other) rules exactly were used to form the solution.

I mean what rule was used to directly do $3 \equiv 5$ and ignore $x$?

Could someone please break down the exact steps the solution is using to reach the conclusion of one solution?

**Update**:
I read the links and comments and I came up with the following steps.
$3x \equiv 5 \mod2 \Leftrightarrow 3x - 5 = 2k\space$ for some $k$
$3x - 5 = 2k \Leftrightarrow 2x + x - 5 = 2k \Leftrightarrow x - 5 = 2k - 2x \Leftrightarrow x - 5 = 2(k - x) \Leftrightarrow x - 5 = 2j\space $ for some $j$

Hence:
$x - 5 = 2j \implies x \equiv 5 (\mod 2) \implies x \equiv 1(\mod 2)$

Comment: @BarryCipra: Typo, corrected it

Comment: Ah, I wondered. In answer to your question, they're not really ignoring the $x$. The coefficients $3$ and $5$ are both odd, so if $m=2$, then $3\equiv1$ and $5\equiv1$ mod $m$. I.e., $x\equiv3x\equiv5\equiv1$ mod $2$. Does that make sense?

Comment: @BarryCipra: Why do you name $5$ a coefficient? It is the congruence class right? Also the confusing part is that it is $3x \equiv 5 \mod 2$ so how do we go directly to $3 \mod 2$? There must be some rule I am not aware

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) on mod as a congruence  relation vs. operation.

Comment: Sorry, a better word choice might have been simply *numbers*.

Comment: @BarryCipra: I understand that $3 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and that $5 \equiv 1 \mod 2$. What I am not clear is what rule do we use to split these $2$ if we start with $3 \equiv 5 \mod 2$

Comment: Where the solution says $3\equiv5\equiv1\mod2$, it's just combining the two separate facts that $3\equiv1\mod2$ and $5\equiv1\mod2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: So $3$ and $5$ are in the same congruence class. And $3 \equiv 3x$ ? That is why we don't take $x$ into account?

Comment: I'm sorry if my attempts to explain things haven't helped. Hopefully something at the links Bill Dubuque has provided will do a better job.

Comment: @BarryCipra: thank you for your comments and trying to help me! I need to re-read the links provided and your comments more carefully to clarify this in my mind. I am sure your explanations do not have a problem at all

Comment: @BarryCipra: I updated my post, is my logic correct?

Comment: @BillDubuque: I updated my post, is my logic correct?

Comment: @Jim, yes, your update looks OK. One possible improvement would be to write the $x-5=2(k-x)$ step as $x-1=2(k-x+2)$ instead. Then you could go straight from $x-1=2j$ for some $j$ to $x\equiv1$ mod $2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Ah thank you for that!

Comment: @Jim, if you can get your hands on a copy of Gauss's *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*, you might take a look at its Section I. In four pages, it lays out the basic theory of modular arithmetic.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Do you recommend some specific translation? Does it require a specific/advanced background?

Comment: The logic is correct (though to be completely rigorous you should write in each equivalent statement the implicit quantifiers "there exists an integer $k$ such that ...". But you should instead use the linked Congruence Rules, which, make this much intuitive. They are the congruence analog of the well known fact that equalities are preserved if we substitute equal values in arithmetic expressions (congruences are generalized equality relations and you should learn to view them just like you do equalities).

Comment: @BillDubuque: Your last comment, the way you have phrased it, it is very helpful to me. Thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 0):

With a polynomial modulo $m$ you can reduce the coefficients of the polynomial modulo $m$ directly because $(ax^k)\mod m = (a)(x^k) \mod m$. This means that for $\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ the integers modulo $n$ that $\varphi (ab) = \varphi (a) \varphi (b)$. It's instructive and accessible to try prove this for yourself given the computational definition of the integers modulo $n$.

Now since you're working modulo $2$ every number will be congruent to $0$ or $1$. This means we can reduce $3x \equiv 5$ to $1x \equiv 1$ which is $x \equiv 1$. Since we only have two choices for $x$ it's easy to see that $1$ is the only solution since $0$ is not.

Comment: I didn't understand how did you use $(ax^k)\mod m = (a)(x^k) \mod m$ and how do we go from $3x$ to $1x$

Comment: @Jim I have expanded my answer to give a you more clarity without spoiling the fun of letting you prove this yourself. It's a common and useful exercise

Comment: I still don't understand how $(ax^k)\mod m = (a)(x^k) \mod m$ is helping/is relevant with the particular question I posted. I think I am misunderstanding something in the logic of your answer

Comment: @Jim everything else is just reduction modulo $2$.

Comment: What does $\varphi$ represent? The $\mod $ operation?

Comment: I updated my post. Is my logic correct?

Comment: @jim yes $\varphi$ is the mod operation written as a function. Your work is correct but unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: `It's instructive and accessible to try prove this for yourself given the computational definition of the integers modulo ` I don't doubt that it is, but I havent really understood what it is that should dig into further to try to prove and understand it. The first paragraph is highly more advanced and rigorous and I am kind of stuck there to be honest