# How do I Multiply Out Modular Division?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I multiply out modular division(s) to simplify for x? I am trying to tackle a coding problem and I'm hopeful that I can simplify the equation in terms of $x$ ($x = ???$) from the following statement:
$$b\mod{x} = x \mod{a}$$

Example:
$x=6$ where $a = 6$ and $b = 36 $:
$$36\mod{6} = 6 \mod{6} = 0$$

All possible values for $a$, $b$, and $x$ are integers that are $\geq 1$ and $\leq 100$. Any steps that can help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi C. I am having trouble to understand your scenario. For example, what exactly does $b\mod{x} = x \mod{a}$ mean?

Comment: I believe this is the computer scientist's use of modulus: the remainder when $b$ is divided by $x$ is the same as the remainder when $x$ is divided by $a$. Is this correct?

Comment: @TomKern that is correct

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Trusting that you are defining $n\pmod m$ as the remainder on dividing $n$ by $m$, then $x$ is not uniquely determined by your equality.  And what do you mean by "asymptotic" in this context?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on $a$, $b$, or $x$?  They're rational, integers, something else?  They're nonnegative, positive, something else?

Comment: @TomKern The $\!\bmod$ *operation* is also used by mathematicians - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) for more.

Comment: Perhaps it would clarify things if you edited your post to include a clear, fully worked, numerical example of the sort of computation you are interested in.

Comment: @EricTowers the constraints are that $x$, $a$, and $b$ are all integers greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 100

Comment: So ... *an* answer is write a small program that, for each $a$ in that range, for each $b$ in that range, for each $x$ in that range, write down the $(a,b,x)$ triples that satisfy the equation you give, then wrap that list in a function that does a lookup in a list indexed by the first two entries of each triple to get the third entry?

Comment: @EricTowers yes that could work - I was just hoping that there was an easier way via simplyfing the above statement somehow. lulu, I removed the asymptotic comment as it wasn't relevant.

Comment: Nonuniqueness immediately appears when you do that:  The triples $(a,b,x) \in \{(1,4,1),(1,4,2),(1,4,4)\}$ ensure that you do not have only one choice of $x$ for a given $a$ and $b$.

Comment: In many computer languages, "the reduction of $a$ modulo $b$", meaning the remainder after integer-dividing $a$ by $b$, is denoted $a\% b$, to distinguish it from "$a$ mod $b$"... although this still conflicts with other uses of the percent sign $\%$

Comment: Even your $b=36, a=6$ example has seven solutions $x \in \{6,7,12,16,18,33,36\}$.

Comment: The reduces your example to four solutions: 6, 12, 18, and 36.  This of course, tells you how to find the $x$s.

Comment: @EricTowers, I see now that my verbage was incorrect. Instead of "solve for $x$", I meant to "simplify in the statement in terms of $x$". As in $x = ???$.

Comment: Yes.  The conditions are insufficient to reduce to a single $x$.  There are four $x$s that satisfy your example.  I've listed them.  Try each of them if you are unsure.

Comment: Thank you @EricTowers! I understand how you reached those values. I was just hoping there was a way to simplify the equation into terms of $x$. Thank you for showing me that is not possible.

Comment: In fact, every $x$ such that the remainder on dividing $b$ by $x$ is zero are the divisors of $b$.  Likewise, the $x$ such that the remainder on dividing $x$ by $a$ is zero are the multiples of $a$.  So you want a multiple of $a$, less than $100$ that also divides $b$.  There need not even be such a number.  Take $a = 2$, $b =3$.  No multiple of $a$ (so, even numbers) divides $b$.