# Why is $4 \mod{-5} = -1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I understand that modulo follows the formula "Quotient × Divisor + Remainder = Dividend," but what I do not understand is how $4 \mod{-5}$ fits as $-1 \times -5 + (-1) = 4$ in the equation. Why isn't it $0 \times (-5) + 4 = 4$, giving us a remainder of $4$ like it does when we do $4 \mod{5}$ in $0 \times 5 + 4 = 4$. What changes when we negate the divisor? How does this make sense?

If the number was greater than five, such as $6$, then negating the $-5$ with a $-1$ like the formula does would make sense, because then you could treat the whole thing as if everything was positive. However I don't understand why $4 \mod (-5)$ is treated the same, why not make the Quotient "$-0$" instead?

Comment: Tell us where you are seeing this behavior. Depends on how you define the mod operator - there are a lot of differences in coding about it. It is non-standard.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See https://torstencurdt.com/tech/posts/modulo-of-negative-numbers/

Comment: @DavidK oh ok, I’ll have a look at it and delete the comment.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) one the relation between mod as an operation vs. congruence relation - which goes to the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Computer languages with integer division generally support a pair of operators:

- `a DIV b` (spelled `//` in Python 2.2+) is the quotient a/b converted to an integer.
- `a MOD b` (often spelled `%`) is the remainder of the division.

For the sake of consistency, MOD must be defined as:

$$a \operatorname{mod} b := a - (a \operatorname{div} b) \cdot b$$

When $a$ and $b$ are both positive, everybody generally agrees that $a \operatorname{div} b = \lfloor \frac{a}{b} \rfloor$.  The confusion comes when negative numbers are involved.

- In C, `4 / -5` is *truncated* towards zero.  So `4 % -5` $= 4 - (0)(-5) = 4$.
- In Python, `4 // -5` is *floored* to $-1$.  So `4 % -5` $= 4 - (-1)(-5) = -1$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque At what point is "recent" no longer the proper descriptor? ;-)