# Modular arithmetic confusion

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am a bit confused about modular arithmetic.
We say that two integers are equal modulo n if their difference
is an integer multiple of n.

So let's take as example: $5(mod2) = 1$, since $5-1 = 4$ which is an integer ($k$) multiple of 2.

But isn't this also true then: $5(mod2) = 3$? Because $5-3 = 2$ which is also an integer multiple of 2, namely $k=1$. If this is true, then why does a calculator just give $5(mod2) = 1$?

Same for $-2(mod7)=5$, why do we pick 5 if there are infinitely many equalities?

Comment: You are confusing mod the **remainder operation** with mod the **congruence relation** - a common source of confusion . See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) in the dupe for further elaboration. Please delete the question once all is clear.