# if x is an integer, then $(x^3+1)\bmod 3 = (x+1)^3 \bmod 3 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Can anyone help me explain why if $x$ is an integer, then $(x^3+1)\bmod 3 = (x+1)^3 \bmod 3$?
I know there are 3 cases. $x=0\bmod3,\ x=1\bmod3,$ and $x=2\bmod3$
totally new to this form of mathematics, could anyone help me setup the proof?

Comment: Consider expanding $(x+1)^3$.

Comment: You could use the cases approach mentioned in the post. Or else you could note that $(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$, so $(x+1)^3$ has the same remainder on division by $3$ as $x^3+1$.

Comment: @BRIC-Fan: I don't quite get your edit. Are you seeing the equations as congruences or binary mods (=remainder operations)? Right now it is a mixture. For example you use equality signs even though your TeX (using `pmod`) suggests that a congruence was intended. At least in the first equation where binary mod (`\bmod`) should be used. I do speak (loudly) against ever using binary mod myself, so this is kinda kettle calling pot, but..? Ok, the original post wasn't entirely clear either :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I see it as a congruence or mod and not really an equation. But it can be viewed as both. Please correct if I am wrong as I am quite a new-b with mathjax.

Comment: aeon1: Judging from the title of your question you may be using `mod` as a remainder operation. However, your syntax is not consistent thoughout the post, and at some points it looks like you might intend a congruence instead. Please study [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) that explains the differences, and explain in your own words how you see it. The reason I'm asking is that your interpretation has an impact on how to the equations/congruences should best be typeset. It is also IMO beneficial to you to be aware of the differences!

Comment: (cont'd) The two ways of using `mod` are closely related, but the syntax is quite different. As is the semantics: binary mod is an arithmetic operation on two numbers that gives a third number as an output. a congruence could be viewed as having three arguments (the last one usually fixed throughout the question) and outputs a boolean value (true/false) in a sense.

Comment: @tonix I highly recommend that you learn the difference between mod as a binary operator vs. ternary congruence, e.g. see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/48003/242).

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use it, by Fermat's Little Theorem $n^3\equiv n\pmod3$.  Using this gives

$$x^3+1\equiv(x+1)^3\equiv x+1\pmod 3$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $3x^2 = 0\pmod 3, 3x = 0 \pmod 3$

Answer (score 0):

$(x+1)^3 -(x^3+1) = 3(x+x^2)$.