# How do I compute x^(-2) mod m?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've written Haskell function, that helps me to compute $x^{-1} \mod m$.

```
invM x m = invMhelp x 0 m; --modular multiplicative inverse x^-1 (mod m) = inv x m  
invMhelp x i m = if (x*i `mod` m == 1) then i else (invMhelp x (i+1) m);
```

For example:

```
Main> 13 `invM` 2109
649
```

That means $13^{-1} = 649 \mod 2109$.

**How can I compute $x^{-2} \mod m$?** ($x^{-2} \mod m = (x^{-1})^2 \mod m$)

**Can I simply use the power of two of the multiplicative inverse and then apply the modulo m again?**

Example: $13^{-1} = 649 \mod 2109$, $649^2 \mod 2109 = 1510$.

Is $13^{-2} \mod 2109$ equal to $1510$?

Sorry for the noob question, but I'm not sure about this. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\rm\: a\equiv b^{-1} \Rightarrow\ a^2 \equiv b^{-2}\: $ via **congruences are preserved by multiplication** (so too by squaring). If you don't yet know that property then you can instead prove the sought result as follows:

$$\rm a\equiv b^{-1}\ \:(mod\ m)\ \Rightarrow\ m\:|\: ab-1\ \Rightarrow\ m|(ab-1)(ab+1)\ =\ a^2 b^2 - 1\ \Rightarrow\ a^2 \equiv b^{-2}\ \:(mod\ m)$$

For completeness, here is the proof that congruences are preserved by mutliplication

**LEMMA** $\rm\ \ A\equiv a,\ B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ AB\equiv ab\ \:(mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ m\: |\: A-a,\:\:\ B-b\ \Rightarrow\ m\ |\ (A-a)\ B + a\ (B-b)\ =\ AB - ab $

This **congruence product rule** is at the heart of many other similar product rules, for example Leibniz's product rule for derivatives in calculus, e.g. see my [post here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/derivative-of-a-product-and-derivative-of-quotient-of-functions-theorem-i-dont/3178#3178)

Comment: In short: you can square before inverting, or invert before squaring.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That will work.

$a \equiv b \pmod{m} \Rightarrow  a^k \equiv b^k \pmod{m}$, whenever $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Sivaram, looks like "\implies" [doesn't work](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/692/tex-implies-symbol-does-not-work). Try "\Rightarrow".

Comment: Thank you, I obviously lack the basic knowledge of the number theory.