# Simplify the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]/(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Simplify the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]/(2)$. I have so far:

$$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-13}]/(2) \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(2, x^2 + 13) \cong \mathbb Z_2[x] / (x^2 + 1)$$

Now how do I simplify it further? I know that $x^2 + 1 = (x + 1)^2$ in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$, is this useful?

Comment: That last identity is useful. I believe that is all that you can say. Interestingly this means the ring has nilpotents! In particular, it's not a domain, and hence 2 is not prime in $Z[\sqrt{-13}]$.

Comment: I don't think the ring structure is either of those. The underlying group, maybe. The ring does not have idempotents, so it can't be a product. Also, the ring has characteristic 2, so it can't be $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$. It is neither of these rings.

Comment: @User0112358 I see, thanks!

Comment: The underlying group structure is $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. But the multiplication is not the coordinate-wise multiplication.

Comment: It's $\cong \Bbb Z_2[t]/(t^2),\,$ the ring of *dual numbers* over $\,\Bbb Z_2.\,$ See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3178/242) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/17151/242) for applications (tangent spaces, product rules, infinitesimals, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Make the substitution $y = x + 1$ to get an isomorphism $(Z/2Z)[x] \cong (Z/2Z)[y]$. The answer is $(Z/2Z)[y]/(y^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+1=0 \Rightarrow x^2=-1 \equiv 1(mod  2) \Rightarrow x^3=x$

$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+..+a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2(-1)+a_3(x)+...=a_0+a_1x(mod 2)$

$\Rightarrow \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+1) =\{I,1+I, x+I,(1+x)+I \}; I=(x^2+1)$

Comment: I don't think this is correct since the ring clearly has 4 elements

Comment: I edit my answer

Comment: How did you get the product?