# Elements of $S=R/2R$ where $R= \mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My approach so far is that for elements ${a + b\sqrt{2}}$ in $S$, $a$ and $b$ just can be $0$ or $1$ (because $a$ and $b$ must be in $\mathbb{2Z}$). So we will have 4 elements: $0,1,\sqrt{2}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}$. Is this right? Is there any proof that shows this better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]\cong \Bbb Z[x]/f,\ f =x^2\!-\!2,\,$ so employing [quotient reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1214702/242) yields

$$\begin{align} \Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]/2 &\,\cong\,  (\Bbb Z[x]/f)\,/\,(2,f)/f\\[.2em] 
&\,\cong\, \ \Bbb Z[x]/(2,f)\\[.2em]
&\,\cong\, (\Bbb Z[x]/2)\,/\,(f,2)/2\\[.2em]
&\,\cong\ \ \Bbb F_2[x]/f \\[.2em]
&\,\cong \ \ \Bbb F_2[x]/x^2
\end{align}\qquad$$

This is the algebra of *dual numbers* over $\Bbb F_2,\,$ used as an [algebraic model of tangent and jet spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17151/242).