# The ring of infinitesimals is the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x] / x^2\mathbb{R}[x].$ What is $(3+x)(3-x)$ in this ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> The ring of infinitesimals is the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x] / x^2\mathbb{R}[x].$ What is $(3+x)(3-x)$ in this ring?

I don't quite understand what this question is asking about.

My thought is that

since $(3+x)(3-x) = 9 - x^2$, it's in the coset of $9 + x^2\mathbb{R}[x]$. When the problem asks that "What is $(3+x)(3-x)$ in this ring", is it asking which coset $(3+x)(3-x)$ is in?  So just $9$?

Comment: So what don't you quite understand then? The questions asks for an element $f$ in this ring $R$ with $f=(3+x)(3-x)$, not as a product, but as the class of a polynomial.

Comment: oh so it's asking what the $f$ in $\mathbb{R}[x] $ transforms into in the given quotient ring?

Comment: It transforms into the constant polynomial $9$, or the class of $9$. Usually we just write $9$.

Comment: It's analogous to asking: what is $3\cdot 4$ in $\Bbb Z_{10}$ or $\bmod 10$?. It refers to  the canonical image in the quotient ring $\ a \mapsto [a],\,$ mapping an element to its coset in the quotient. Here the image is the first order taylor approximation ("tangent"). This ring is known as the algebra of [dual numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17151/242). It provides a convenient algebraic  model of tangent and jet spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The quotient ring is the set of modulo-$x^2$ equivalence classes of elements of $\Bbb R[x]$. The unique polynomial equivalent to $9-x^2$ of degree less than that of $x^2$ is a degree-$0$ polynomial, $x\mapsto9$. So whether the question asks for this polynomial or the equivalence class containing it, the answer is respectively $x\mapsto 9$ or $\{x\mapsto x^2p(x)+9|p(x)\in\Bbb R[x]\}$.