# Divisibility Mathematical Induction Help

Tags: induction

Could you please help me with this question prove that $\displaystyle5^n + 2\cdot(11)^n$ is a multiple of $3$.

Thanks

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: the proving for n=k+1

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614219/induction-proof-for-n-in-mathbb-n-9-mathrel-4n6n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

After you check for $\;n=1\;$ the inductive step is:

$$5^{n+1}+2\cdot 11^{n+1}=5\left(5^n+2\cdot 11^n\right)+6\cdot 2\cdot 11^n\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{align*}5^{k+1}+2\cdot11^{k+1}&=5\cdot5^k+2\cdot11\cdot11^k\\
&=5\cdot5^k+2\cdot(\color{red}5+\color{blue}6)\cdot11^k\\
&=5\cdot5^k+\color{red}{2\cdot5\cdot11^k}+\color{blue}{2\cdot6\cdot11^k}\\
&=5(5^k+\color{red}{2\cdot11^k})+\color{blue}{2\cdot6\cdot11^k}\\
&=5(5^k+\color{red}{2\cdot11^k})+\color{blue}{3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot11^k}\\\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Base case: n = 0
$$5^0+2(11)^0 = 1 + 2 = 3$$
Inductive case: suppose the hypothesis holds for $n\le k$
$$5^{k+1} + 2(11)^{k+1}= 5 5^{k} + (6+5)2(11)^{k}=\cdots$$