# How to prove $5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2$ is divisible by $30$ for even $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, induction

How to prove $5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2$  is divisible by $30$ for all positive even integer $n$?

Here are my efforts:

Let $f(n)=5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2$.

For $n=2$,
$$f(1)=5^{2\cdot 2+1}-3^{2\cdot2+1}-2=2880=30\times 96$$
So, the statement is true for $n=2$.

Assume the statement is true for some integer $k\geq 2$.
$$f(k)=5^{2k+1}-3^{2k+1}-2=30t$$

For $n=k+2$,

\begin{align}
f(k+2)&=(5^{2(k+2)+1})-(3^{2(k+2)+1})-2\\
&=(5^4)\cdot (5^{(2k+1)})-(3^4)\cdot (3^{(2k+1)})-2
\\&=30(80t)+160+544\cdot (5^{2k+1})
\end{align}
I'm stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you have the choice how to prove this : Easier is to show that the expression is divisible by $2,3$ and $5$.

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an induction proof, but I'll nevertheless leave it here.*

To show that $5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2$ is divisble by $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$, you can show that $2,3,5$ divides it.

- $2\mid 5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2\iff 2\mid 5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}$, but this is clear since the sum of two odd numbers is even.
- $3\mid 5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2\iff 3\mid 5^{2n+1}-2$, write $5^{2n+1}-2$ as $$(6-1)^{2n+1}-2$$ Upon expanding, every term is a multiple of $6$, and the last term is $(-1)^{2n+1}-2=-3$. So everything is divisible by $3$.
- $5\mid 5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2\iff 5\mid -3^{2n+1}-2$. Same trick, rewrite $-3^{2n+1}-2$ as $$-3(10-1)^n-2$$ Upon expanding every term except the last term is divisible by $5$, the last term is $-3(-1)^n-2$, so the result is only true for even $n$.

The claim is only true for even $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an *intuitive* way to do an inductive proof that doesn't require knowledge of modular arithmetic yet remains faithful to its *arithmetical* genesis.

Take notice that $\ 5\cdot 25^n - 3\cdot 9^m - 2\,$ is a special case of below

**Theorem** $\,\ 30\mid 5(1\!+\!6a)^n - 3(1\!+\!10b)^m - 2,\,$ for $\,a,b\in\Bbb Z,\, n,m\in\Bbb N.\ \ \ $ **Proof:**

By induction on $\,n\,$[we can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/733169/242) $\, 5(1+6a)^n\! =\, 5 + 30j\ $ for some $\ j\in\Bbb Z.\,$ By the same proof
by induction on $m$ we can show $\,3(1\!+\!10b)^m\! =\:\! 3 + 30k\,$ for some $\,k\in \Bbb Z$

Subtracting them and $\,2\,$ yields $\,5(1\!+\!6a)^n - 3(1\!+\!10b)^m - 2 = 30(j-k).\ \ {\small\bf QED}$

**Remark** $ $ Here the employed induction is much more intuitive, essentially amounting to an inductive proof of the first couple terms of the Binomial Theorem, as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/733169/242). When you learn modular arithmetic such inductions become neatly encapsulated for handy reuse by applications of the *Congruence Power Rule*, as [explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/794719/242). In particular we can use the handy [mDL law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242)

$$\begin{align} ab\bmod ac\, &=\, a(b\bmod c) = \text{$\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law [mDL]}\\[.3em]
\Rightarrow\ 5(1\!+\!6a)^n \bmod 30\, &=\, 5((1\!+\!6a)^n\bmod 6) = 5(\color{#c00}{1^n}\!\bmod 6 ) = 5(\color{#c00}1)\end{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

which reduces the proof to an extremely *trivial induction* $\,\color{#c00}{1^n\equiv 1}.\,$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(k)=5^{2k+1}-3^{2k+1}-2=30t$

for $n=k+2$,
\begin{align}f(k+2)&=5^{2(k+2)+1}-3^{2(k+2)+1}-2\\
&=(5^4)\cdot (5^{2k+1})-(3^4)\cdot (3^{2k+1})-2\\
&=30(80t)+160+544\cdot (5^{2k+1}) \\
&= 30(80t) + 150 + 10 + 540(5^{2k+1}) + 4(5^{2k+1})\end{align}

It suffices to prove that $10+4(5^{2k+1})$ is divisible by $30$.

\begin{align}
10 + 4(5^{2k+1}) &= 10 + 20(5^{2k})
\end{align}

It is clearly divisible by $10$, we just have to show that it is divisible by $3$.

$$10+20(5^{2k}) \equiv 1-2^{2k}\equiv 1-4^k = 1-1^k \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$

Hence is it divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2=5^{2n+1}-5-3\cdot3^{2n}+3=5^{2n+1}-5-3\left(81^{\frac{n}{2}}-1\right)=$$$$=5^{2n+1}-5-3\cdot80\left(81^{\frac{n}{2}-1}+...+1\right),$$
we see that $5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2$ is divisible by $5$.

Also, $$5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2=5^{2n+1}+1-\left(3^{2n+1}+3\right)=(5+1)(5^{2n}-...+1)-\left(3^{2n+1}+3\right),$$
which says that $5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2$ is divisible by $6$.

Id est, $5^{2n+1}-3^{2n+1}-2$ is divisible by $30$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $g(n)=f(2n)=5\cdot 625^n-3\cdot 81^n-2\cdot1^n$. Then
$$
g(n+3)= 707 g(n+2) - 51331 g(n+1) + 50625 g(n)
$$
because $(x-625)(x-81)(x-1)=0$ can be written $x^3=707 x^2 - 51331 x + 50625$. (The important point here is that the coefficients are integers, not their exact values.)

Therefore, the claim follows at once by induction if it holds for $n=0,1,2$:
$$
g(0)=0, \quad g(1)=2880 = 30 \cdot 96, \quad g(2)= 1933440 = 30 \cdot 64448
$$
(No need to compute the quotient: it's easy to see that they are all multiples of $3$ and $10$.)

Actually, $g(n)$ is divisible by $960=\gcd(g(0),g(1),g(2))$.