# Induction with divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

QUESTION: Prove that $16 \mid 19^{4n+1}+17^{3n+1}-4$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure where to go from here.

PROOF:
Let $16 \mid 19^{4n+1}+17^{3n+1}-4$ equal $S(n)$.
Base case, let $n=0$.
\begin{align*}
16 &\mid 191+171-4\\
  = 16 & \mid 32\\
  = 2
\end{align*}
Therefore, $S(0)$ is true.

Using induction hypothesis, suppose $19^{4k+1}+17^{3k+1}-4$ is divisible by $16$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Claim,
$16 \mid 19^{4k+1}+17^{3k+1}-4$,
that is $19^{4k+1}+17^{3k+1}-4=16m$, whereby $m$ is a multiple of $16$.
The above equation simplifies into,
\begin{align*} 
16 & \mid 19^{4n+5}+17^{3n+4}-4\\
16 & \mid 19^4 \cdot 19^{4k+1} + 17^3 \cdot 17^{3n+1}-4
\end{align*}

[photo of my working out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDHiP.png)

Comment: Hint: have you tried to evaluate $19^4\bmod{16}$ and $17^3\bmod{16}$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: As a further hint to make the arithmetic easier... note that $19 = 16+3$ so $19^4 = (16+3)^4 = \underbrace{16^4+4\cdot 16^3\cdot 3 + \dots + 4\cdot 16\cdot 3^3}_{\text{multiple of }16} + 3^4$... you don't actually have to deal with such large numbers as $19^4$ which people generally don't have memorized and can deal with the much smaller $3^4$ which people generally do.  Similarly for $17=16+1$

Comment: That's just a long way to say that if $A\equiv a\pmod{k}$ then $A^n \equiv a^n\pmod{k}$

Comment: Two comments:  $16 \mid 32$ means that there exists some integer $x$ such that $16x =32$.  Do not confuse it with $32/16$.  Also, your induction hypothesis should be the statement that there exists some integer $k$ such that $16 \mid 19^{4k + 1} + 17^{3k + 1} - 4$, not that $16$ divides that quantity for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, which is what you want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Q. Show that $16$ $|$ $19^{4n+1} +17^{3n+1} -4$  $\forall$ $ n \in \mathbb N$.

First of all, simplify the expression. Write $19=16+3$ and $17=16+1$, then use binomial theorem to expand it. That way you'll get a simpler expression to use induction.

$16$ $|$  $19^{4n+1} +17^{3n+1} -4 \implies$ $16$ $|$ $3^{4n+1}+1-4 \implies 16$ $|$ $3(3^{4n}-1)$

$\implies 16$ $|$ $3^{4n}-1$.

**Method 1 to proceed:**

Now here it's easier to just use the fact that $x-y$ $|$ $x^n-y^n$, because it will prove that $ 16$ $|$ $3^{4n}-1$ directly, without induction. ( As $16$ $|$ $3^4 -1$  $|$ $3^{4n}-1$. )

But if you wish to use induction only, then here it is:

**Method 2 to proceed:**

Let $P(n):16$ $|$ $3^{4n}-1$.

$P(1), P(2)$ are true.

Let $P(i)$ be true for $i=1,2,\cdots,k$

$16$ $|$ $3^{4n}-1 \implies 16$ $|$ $(3^{4n}-1)(3^4+1) \implies 16$ $|$ $3^{4n+4}-1 +3^{4}(3^{4n-4}-1)$

And we know $16 $ $|$ $(3^{4n-4}-1)$ (As $P(n-1)$ is true).

$\implies 16$ $|$ $3^{4n+4}-1 \implies P(n+1)$ is true, and hence $P(n)$ is true for all natural numbers $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\!\bmod 16\!:\ \color{#c00}{19^{4n}}\equiv 3^{4n}\equiv (3^4)^n\equiv 1^n\!\equiv\color{#c00}1,$ and $\,\color{#0a0}{17^k}\equiv 1^k\!\equiv\color{#0a0}1\,$ by CPR = [Congruence Power Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)
hence $\,19(\color{#c00}{19^{4n}})+\color{#0a0}{17^{4n+1}}\!-4\equiv 19(\color{#c00}{1})+\color{#0a0}1-4\equiv 0.\,$ CPR has a [short and simple inductive proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) (simply iterate the Congruence Product Rule).

**Or** w/o mod: $ $ it is $\,19(\color{#c00}{19^{4n}-1)} + \color{#0a0}{17^n\!-\!1} + 16\,$ and $\,16\mid \color{#0a0}{17^n\!-\!1}\,$ by FT = Factor Theorem, and $\,\color{#c00}{19^{4n}\!-\!1} = 19^{4n}-3^{4n}+\color{#90f}{3^{4n}\!-\!1}\,$ and by FT: $\,19\!-\!3\mid 19^{4n}\!-\!3^{4n},\,$ $\,16\mid 3^4\!-\!1\mid \color{#90f}{3^{4n}\!-\!1}.\,$ Again FT has a short simple inductive proof: hint $\,a^{n+1}\!-\!b^{n+1} = (a\!-\!b)a^n +b(a^n\!-\!b^n)$.

Note how the above divisibilities are essentially proving the same congruences as above, but in a more cumbersome way due to use of relations (divisibility) vs. operations (arithmetic $\!\bmod 16$)

**Remark** $ $ Just as above, generally using congruences makes inductions like this very easy, reducing them to *trivialities* like $\,a\equiv 1\Rightarrow\, a^n\equiv 1,\,$ as explained at length in many prior answers, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1179145/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/794719/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3838498/242). This innate arithmetical (power) structure is usually greatly obfuscated in direct inductive proofs - which often greatly complicates the discovery (and comprehension) of the key inductive step

Answer (score 0):

To show $16  \mid 19^4 \cdot 19^{4k+1} + 17^3 \cdot 17^{3n+1}-4$ given $16 \mid 19^{4k+1}+17^{3k+1}-4$, note that

$19^4 \cdot 19^{4k+1} + 17^3 \cdot 17^{3n+1}-4=$

$17^3\color{blue}{(19^{4k+1}+17^{3n+1}-4)} + \color{blue}{(19^4-17^3)}\cdot19^{4n+1}+
\color{blue}{(17^3\cdot4-4)},$

and all of the blue terms are divisible by $16$.