# Prove (or disprove) that $3^{2n+3}+40n-27$ is divisible by $64$ for any $n$ integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

So I want to prove that is in title. I'm working with modular arithmetic, so if any of you can show me a hint, it will be perfect.

Comment: *Hint:* Let $x_n = 3^{2n+3}+40n-27$. Compute $x_{n+1}-x_{n} = 8 (3^{2 n + 3} + 5)
\bmod 64$.

Comment: @lhf Easier to use $\ x_{n+1}-\color{#c00}9\,x_n = 64(4-5n).\ $ This works generally - see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2958598/242) in the dupe.

Answer (score 3):

We find that
$$
\frac{3^{2n+3}+40n-27}{8}=\frac{27(9^n-1)+40n}{8}=27(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}+\cdots+1)+5n.
$$ And also
$$
27(9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}+\cdots+1)+5n\equiv 27(1+1+\cdots +1)+5n\equiv32n\equiv 0\ \;\text{(mod}\;8).
$$ Therefore $64 \;|\; 3^{2n+3}+40n-27$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: i understand, so your answer is reducible to say "if is divisible by 8, too is divisible by 8^2" ?

Comment: @RichardKingston Basically, yes. If $8\ | \ N$ and $8\ | \ (N/8)$, then it holds $64 \ | \ N$ .

Answer (score 0):

Use induction and modular arithmetic: suppose that, for some $n$, $3^{2n+3}+40n-27\equiv 0\mod64$. We have to show that
$$3^{2n+5}+40(n+1)-27=9\cdot3^{2n+3}+40n+13\equiv 0\mod64.$$
The inductive hypothesis can be rewritten as
$$3^{2n+3}\equiv -40n +27\mod64,$$
 so that
$$9\cdot3^{2n+3}+40n+13\equiv-360n+243+40m+13=-320n+256\equiv 0\mod 64. $$