# A question about mathematical induction and divisibility

Tags: induction, divisibility

I am reading the book '[Essential](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1138442577/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_taft_p1_i2) Engineering Mathematics' by Alan Jeffrey.
There is one example that asks to prove, by mathematical induction, that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ the number
$$
2^{n+2}\times 3^n+5n-4
$$
is divisible by 25. I do not have any issues with the proof (or similar proofs). My question is may be a dubious one: how can one arrive at asserting a proposition like the above in the first place?

Comment: It is easy to see the number is divisible by $5$: $2^{n+2}\times 3^n = 4\times 6^n$; since $6$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when dividided by $5$, this number leaves a remainder of $4$ when divided by $5$, so $2^{n+2}\times 3^n -4$ is a multiple of $5$, and hence so is $2^{n+2}\times 3^n + 5n - 4$. Modulo $25$ you have to work a bit more more; the powers of $6$ modulo $25$ cycle as $6\mapsto 11\mapsto 16\mapsto 21\mapsto 1\mapsto 6$, so you can consider the different possible values of $n$ in turn and verifying the result is divisible by $25$.

Comment: You can also note that $(1+5)^n \equiv 1 + 5 n \mod 5^2$ by the binomial theorem.

Comment: You mean: How in the world could anybody ever figure out that  $2^n+7^n+8^n+18^n+19^n+24^n=3^n+4^n+12^n+14^n+22^n+23^n \text{ for } n =0,1,...,5$ Some things remain a mystery to me.

Comment: Such divisibilities (or congrunces) arise immediately from the Binomial Theorem (or from recurrences or closely related results) - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614369/2420) and its links in the linked dupe for a general form of such. Write it as $\,f_n = 4(6^n)+5n-5\,$ then apply the linked Theorem.