# Why do derivatives pop up in abstract algebra?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

Why is it that derivatives, which are used in calculus, are also useful in abstract algebra concerning abstract polynomial rings? What is the connection between calculus and algebra here?

Comment: One application: formal derivatives can be used to help identify repeated roots of members of polynomial rings.

Comment: You ask if you knew derivatives are useful in abstract algebra, but you don't explain why you think so.

Comment: If $P$ is a polynomial, we may need information about $P(x+a)-P(x)$. One example is in Hensel lifting.  The derivative here is a formal derivative, which can be defined purely algebraically, but it coincides with the ordinary derivative.

Comment: Follow the [links here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3178/242)

Comment: Every kind of derivations can be defined in abstract algebra, and the key connection is the Leibniz rule for products ($(fg)'=f'g+fg'$) and this in itself is written purely algebraically, in the language of rings (uses addition and multipliction).

Comment: @GitGud I know that they are used in abstract algebra (sometimes it seems like just a "trick"). But I am asking why we have these things that came into being thru distance/ topological concerns (specifically calculus) being transposed into a non-topological, no-distances type of arena.

Answer (score 1):

Partial derivatives can give information about "functional dependence".
Here is a fact that is easy for polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ but is true in general for polynomials over any  [perfect field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field).

Let $\phi_1$, $\ldots$, $\phi_n$ be $n$ polynomials in $n$ variables $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_n$ over a field $F$. Assume that the jacobian determinant $\det (\frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_j})$ is not the zero polynomial. Then the $\phi_i$'s are functionally independent, that is, there does not exist a non-zero polynomial $P$ such that $P(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n ) \equiv 0$.

Assume such $P$ there exists and take one of minimal degree. From the equality  $P(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n ) = 0$ we get a system of equations in $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y_i}(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n)$:
$$\sum_i \frac{\partial P}{\partial y_i}(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n)\cdot \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_j}= 0$$
$j=1,\ldots, n$ and so by Cramer
$$\det (\frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x_j}) \cdot \frac{\partial P}{\partial y_k}(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n)=0$$
for all $k = 1,\ldots, n$ and since the jacobian is nonzero and the ring of polynomials is a domain, we get $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y_k}(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n)\equiv 0$ for all $k=1,\ldots, n$. Since $P$ was chosen of minimal degree we get $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y_k}(y_1, \ldots, y_n) \equiv 0$, and so $P$ is either a constant polynomial (in the case char $F = 0$) or a polynomial in $y_i^p$ if char $F= p$. Now since $F$ is perfect, in the second case we necessarily have $P = Q^p$ for some $Q \in F[y_1, \ldots, y_n]$. In either case we get a contradiction.

Note that if we were working over $\mathbb{R}$ this meant that around any point where the jacobian is not $0$ the map $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto (\phi_1(x), \ldots, \phi_n(x))$ is a local diffeomorphism (analytic in fact) so the image of the map $\phi$ contains an open set, hence it is "Zariski dense".

$\bf{Added:}$ Let $R_1$, $\ldots$, $R_{k+1}$ rational functions of several variables such that the jacobian matrices of $(R_1, \ldots, R_k)$ and $(R_1, \ldots, R_{k+1})$ have the same rank. Then $R_{k+1}$ is algebric over $(R_1,\ldots, R_k)$. Indeed, otherwise there would exist an $F$ derivation of the field $F(x_i)$ that is $0$ on $R_1$, $\ldots$, $R_k$, but $1$ on $R_{k+1}$, but this is not possible, because of the rank condition on the jacobians.

Comment: It seems "functionally independent" is in fact *algebraically independent*.

Comment: @user26857: Correct, in the case of polynomials. However, a similar result holds for analytic functions, or smooth, so it's useful to have a wide  perspective.