# Unclear Proving the Product Derivative rule using the definition of a derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

I am trying to prove the product rule derivative using the definition of the derivative.

> Definition of derivative --> $h'(c)= \lim_{ n \to 0} = \frac{h(c+n) - h(c)}{n}$

> Prove $h'(c) = f'(c)g(c) + f(c)g'(c) $

$h'(c)= \lim_{ n \to 0} = \frac{h(c+n) - h(c)}{n} = \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{f(c+n)g(c+n) - f(c)g(c)}{n}$

$\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{(f(c+n)g(c+n) - f(c+n)g(c)) - (f(c+n)g(c)- f(c)g(c))}{n}$

$\lim_{n \to 0} f(c+n)( \frac{g(c+n)-g(c)}{n}) + \lim_{n \to 0} g(c) \frac{f(c+n)+f(c)}{n}$

From the above its easy to see that it is equals to - $h'(c) = f'(c)g(c) + f(c)g'(c) $

But I have major confusions on:

> $\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{(f(c+n)g(c+n) - f(c+n)g(c)) - (f(c+n)g(c)- f(c)g(c))}{n}$

How did this happen from $\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{f(c+n)g(c+n) - f(c)g(c)}{n}$

Comment: It seems you have mixed together the product and chain rules. They are quite different.

Comment: Do you want to prove the product rule or chain rule?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivative of a product and derivative of quotient of functions theorem: I don't understand its proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/derivative-of-a-product-and-derivative-of-quotient-of-functions-theorem-i-dont)

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo  when you write $\frac{(f(c+n)g(c+n) - f(c+n)g(c)) - (f(c+n)g(c)- f(c)g(c))}{n}$. You have

$$ \frac{(f(c+n)g(c+n) - f(c)g(c))}{n} = \frac{(f(c+n)g(c+n) - f(c+n)g(c)) + (f(c+n)g(c)- f(c)g(c))}{n}$$

Comment: how did you get from the 2nd to 3rd line? it does not make any sense to me

Comment: @user307640 In the third line you have  $- f(c+n)g(c)) + f(c+n)g(c) = 0$.